# How to get all existing device registrations of push in IBM MFP

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app, worklight-server, worklight-runtime

I have followed rest API(linked below) tutorial to get all the device registrations of push notifications in MFP. But I am getting maximum size of 5000 records, but I need all the device registrations. **Kindly help me.**
[restapi_push_device_registrations_get](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/rest_runtime/r_restapi_push_device_registrations_get.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get all the device registration records in a single REST call as 5000 is the maximum limit.

However you can achieve this using offset and size parameter of Mobilefirst Push Device Registrations (GET) Endpoint.

- Pass size as 5000 and offset as 0 returns first 5000 device registration records
- Pass size as 5000 and offset as 5000 returns next 5000 device registration
  records.